# How can I solve this system using Laplace transforms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve using Laplace transforms: $y''+y=G(t)$, $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ where

$$G(t) = \begin{cases} t~~~~~~~~~~~~~~0\leq t\leq\pi\\
2\pi-t ~~~~~ \pi\leq t \leq 2\pi \\
0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ t\geq 2\pi
\end{cases}$$

Now, I found the Laplace transform of the LHS to be $s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+Y(s)$. I also said that $G(t)=t(1-u_\pi(t))+(2\pi-t)(u_\pi(t)-u_{2\pi}(t))$ where $u_c(t)$ is the unit step function. I am confused as to how to take the Laplace transform of $G(t)$ as I do not know what to do when multiplying by a difference of step functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes people trip over the step function notation.  Simply work with the definition of $G$ as you have written it:

$$\begin{align}G(s) &= \int_0^{\pi} dt \, t \, e^{-s t} + \int_{\pi}^{2 \pi} dt \, (2 \pi-t) \, e^{-s t}\\ &= -\frac{d}{ds} \frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{s} + 2 \pi \frac{e^{-\pi s}-e^{-2 \pi s}}{s}+\frac{d}{ds} \frac{e^{-\pi s}-e^{-2\pi s}}{s}\\ &= \frac{e^{-2 \pi  s} \left(e^{\pi  s}-1\right)^2}{s^2}\end{align}$$

Thus the LT of the solution is

$$Y(s) = \frac{e^{-2 \pi  s} \left(e^{\pi  s}-1\right)^2}{s^2 (s^2+1)}$$

The solution is the inverse LT

$$y(t) = \frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \frac{e^{-2 \pi  s} \left(e^{\pi  s}-1\right)^2}{s^2 (s^2+1)}e^{s t} $$

To evaluate this, I would first expand the numerator to get

$$y(t) = \frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \left (\frac{e^{s t}}{s^2 (s^2+1)} - 2 \frac{e^{s (t-\pi)}}{s^2 (s^2+1)} + \frac{e^{s (t-2\pi)}}{s^2 (s^2+1)}\right )$$

You can evaluate this either by the residue theorem, or by a lookup table.  Note that the second and third term involve shifting time, so there will be step functions in the solution beyond the usual $\theta(t)$.  As this is homework, I will leave the solution to you.